# Image on every corner of page

Tags: latex

i have an image and want it to be on every corner of the page(aligning with the border i specified with the usepackage geometry).
The page doesn't contain anything else.

i tried calculating the distances, but it didn't work this way(the distance on the right is too short)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{img}
        \hspace{10mm}
        \includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{img}
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{9mm}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{img}
        \hspace{10mm}
        \includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{img}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

is there a way to tell latex to put them exactly in the corners? i want to this for mutiple pages, but with a different image on each page

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tikz` for absolute positioning of nodes on the page. For example:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {
    \includegraphics[…]{…}
};
```

This will place the node at the top-left (north west) corner of the page. It will also put it's anchor there so that it will not be centered at that point. You can do for the other corners accordingly.

To use this command, I *believe* but might be wrong, you only need the base package:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the spaces yourself, instead you can use `\hfill` and `\vfill`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{example-image-duck}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{example-image-duck}%
\vfill
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{example-image-duck}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=80mm, height=120mm]{example-image-duck}%
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]